# Groovy Operator Overloading Increment/Decrement Error

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, overloading

I have the following Groovy code snippet that is attempting to use operator overloading for increment, decrement and equals.  All this does is create two instances, perform the increment and a decrement one one of the instances and then compare the two instances using the overloaded methods equals.  When I do the comparison it fails.  Both should be 100 when this code completes. (the print statements show it, but one of the `toString()` functions appear to be wrong).  What am I doing wrong here?

This is with groovy 1.8.6

```
class Overload {
    def value

    public Overload(value = 0) {
        this.value = value
    }

    def next() {
        value = value + 1;
    }

    def previous() {
        value = value - 1;
    }

    def boolean equals(other) {
        if (value == other?.value) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    def String toString() {
        "value is = ${value}"
    }
}

def cls1 = new Overload(100)
def cls2 = new Overload(100)

cls1++
cls1--
if (cls1 == cls2) {
    println("cls1 == cls2")
}
else {
    println("cls1 != cls2")
}

println(cls1.toString())
println(cls2.toString())
```

Output:

```
cls1 != cls2
100
value is = 100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the increment and decrement methods of the `Overload` instance.

Groovy has the feature of implicit return for the last expression evaluated. When you call to `cls1++`, now the object is an Integer, that's the reason we not see the output from the overrided `toString`method.

```
def next() {
    value = value + 1
    return this
}

def previous() {
    value = value - 1
    return this
}
```

Check now:

```
assert cls1.class == Overload
assert cls2.class == Overload
assert cls1 == cls2
assert cls1 == 100
assert cls2 == 100
```

Comment: Oh my, that is weird.  So groovy is autoboxing the return and converting the whole class on a unary operation.  Ouch.  I didn't realize that it had a return in this case and that it would do that.  Thank you, that really helped.  I'll have to be more careful with this.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick additional comment, you don't need to be using `def` when defining the return type of your methods.  A cleaner version of your class is:

```
class Overload {
    def value

    public Overload(value = 0) {
        this.value = value
    }

    def next() {
        value = value + 1
        this
    }

    def previous() {
        value = value - 1
        this
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        value == other?.value
    }

    String toString() {
        "value is = ${value}"
    }
}
```